# OnActivityResult returns a who=null error

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, onactivityresult

First Activity (classDetails.class)

//addStudent Button

```
             Button addStudent = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addStudent2);
        addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //on click, start activity for result
                Intent addStudent = new Intent(ClassDetails.this, AddStudent.class);

                 addStudent.putExtra("position", classPosition);
                startActivityForResult(addStudent,3);
            }
        });
     }
```

Second Activity (addStudent.class):
        //Save Button

```
    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton1);  
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            //get student name
            studentName = inputName.getText().toString();

            //convert classID to int and check if entry is a number
            try {
                studentNum = Integer.parseInt(inputID.getText().toString());
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {

                 Context context = getApplicationContext();
                 CharSequence text = "Please Enter a Number";
                 int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                 toast.show(); 

            } 
                //use studentNum as string
            studentN = Integer.toString(studentNum); 

            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("name", studentName);
            returnIntent.putExtra("number", studentN);

            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);   

             Log.d(TAG, "rusult OK set");

             finish();
    }
    });
```

First Activity (classDetails.class):
//take activity result from Add Student

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if (requestCode == 3) {

         if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
             Log.d(TAG, "classDetail result from addStudent OK");

             String studentName = data.getExtras().getString("name");  
             String studentNum = data.getExtras().getString("number");
             //convert studentNum to int
             int studentN = Integer.parseInt(studentNum);

             //add student to database
             myData = DataStore.getInstance();
             ArrayList<Student> studentList = myData.getClassArray().get(classPosition).getList();
             Student newStudent = new Student();
             newStudent.setInputName(studentName);
             newStudent.setInputID(studentN);

             studentList.add(newStudent);

             updateStudentList(classPosition, newStudent.getInputName());

             //student added toast
             Context context = getApplicationContext();
             CharSequence text = studentName + " Added";
             int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
             toast.show(); 
      }
         if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
             Context context = getApplicationContext();
             CharSequence text = "No Student Added";
             int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

             //Set listView
            classView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapterClass = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, studentNames);    
            classView.setAdapter(adapterClass);

             Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
             toast.show();
         }
      }



    }//onActivityResult
```

LogCat:

```
 03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Process: com.example.classorganizer, PID: 2883
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=3, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.classorganizer/com.example.classorganizer.ClassDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3365)

    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.example.classorganizer.ClassDetails.onActivityResult(ClassDetails.java:133)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
    03-04 00:35:19.109: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: what is line number 133 in your `ClassDetails.java`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
        Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("name", studentName);
        returnIntent.putExtra("number", studentN);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines

```
String studentName = data.getExtras().getString("name");  
                String studentNum = data.getExtras().getString("number");
```

With

```
String studentName = data.getStringExtra("name");  
                String studentNum = data.getStringExtra("number");
```